# Serviço para envio de SMS ou Push Notification

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, typescript

Possuo uma aplicação desenvolvida em Angular 7 que está em fase final de desenvolvimento. Esta aplicação faz o uso dos serviços do Firebase, uma delas é o Cloud Firestore.

Estou procurando uma forma de como ter um serviço que fique rodando diariamente sem parar, que identifique quando deve enviar um SMS alertando o usuário de um compromisso que ele tem mesmo que ele esteja com o sistema fechado, ou então enviar um Push Notification usando Cloud Messaging se possível.

De que forma consigo enviar um SMS de lembrete pegando um compromisso salvo no Firestore, verificando a hora e o dia e enviando um SMS ou Push Notification sem que o usuário precise estar conectado ao sistema?

Acredito que eu teria que ter um serviço em um servidor rodando diariamente sem parar fazendo as leituras no banco de dados, mas existe algo na Internet que faz isso pra mim sem que eu tenha que ter um servidor própio?

Comment: Tem alguns sites que fazem cron jobs pra vc. Ou seja depedendo de alguns parametros eles fazem uma tarefa depois de um certo período mas no seu caso ele teria que chamar algum serviço seu pra mandar o sms. Ou seja vc teria um serviço seu de envio de sms e um outro de CRON que chama ele com um certo periodo.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tem duas coisas diferentes na sua pergunta.

Primeira, como rodar um serviço direto, isso é totalmente não recomendado, no universo de Saas onde está o Firebase, isso geraria um custo enorme, o recomendado no seu caso seria usar uma ferramenta de cron job, como por exemplo https://www.easycron.com ou https://runcloud.io/, o importante é que ele aceite agendamentos via API.

Segunda, enviar e-mail, e sms automaticamente, você pode usar qualquer serviço como https://sendgrid.com/ e https://www.twilio.com/ respectivamente, eles tem APIs para você enviar os dados

e a chave que conecta as duas coisas são os triggers do Firebase, com eles você pode criar um Function que é acionada sempre que os dados são adicionados no Firestore https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?hl=pt-br

com esse conjunto você consegue, Agendar um Cron via api toda vez que os dados forem adicionados no firestore, e pode criar outra function http pra ser acionada nao por trigger mas pelo cron no momento programado, essa segunda function acionaria as API de sms, email, push, ou o que mais você queira.